# Programmatically simulate a Key Down event using Arrow Keys using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to simulate using Arrow Keys to behave the same was as Enter. I am using an APEX Interactive Grid and I have been able to make it work for the ArrowDown key to map to the Enter Key. I need to be able to do the same for ArrowUp key but instead of Enter, I need it to behave an Shift-Enter. There is no one key for that as it's a combination of 13 (Enter) and Shift (16).

Here is my code for ArrowDown. Any idea of how to simulate the Shift-Enter?

```
$("#source").keydown(function(e) {  
  if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {  
    e.preventDefault();  
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");  
    e.which = 13  
    $('#source').trigger(e);  
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check .shiftKey which returns a boolean indicating if the key is pressed. Placing this conditional around your switch will prevent any events from occurring unless the key is pressed in combination with shift.

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt){
        evt = evt || window.event;
        if(evt.shiftKey){
        switch (evt.keyCode){
            case 67:
                createNewFile();
                break;
            case 82:
                goToRecords();
                break;
            case 84:
                goToToday();
                break;
            case 36:
                goToMsHome();
                break;
            case 27:
               escToCloseOptions();
                break;
            case 83:
               summary();
                break;  
            case 73:
               insertRecord();
                break;          
        }
      }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks Felipe. I believe that doing this would capture the Shift Key in combination with the Enter key. However, can I simulate the fact that when I press Up Arrow (40), I am really saying do, Shift-Enter?

Comment: you tried?
document.onkeydown = function(evt){
        evt = evt || window.event;
        if(evt.shiftKey){
        switch (evt.keyCode){
            case 40:
                console.log('shift+arrowdown');
                break;
             
        }
      }
    };

Comment: I believe that would work. Here is what I landed up doing:

$("#source").keydown(function(e) {  
  if (e.key === 'ArrowUp') {  
    e.preventDefault();  
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");  
    e.which = 13
    e.shiftKey = true;
    $('#source').trigger(e);  
  }  
});